# Spring boot return 404 given that debugger hits the breakpoint I set in the controller. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot

I used IntelliJ to create a web application with Spring boot which runs on Tomcat using Mustache and Gradle.

My TestController.java and TestApplication.java are in the same package (com.example.test).

Here is the TestApplicaiton.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the TestController:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView index(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

I put the `index.html` under both `/resources/static` and `/resources/templates`. Still, the page says

> 404 not found (Whitelabel Error Page).

If I change the @controller annotation to @RestController and change the return type to String, it returns the string properly.

So, it seems like something went wrong when resolving the view. However, it doesn't throw an exception. I noticed that mvContainer view is null when I stepped into the code.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure `ViewResolver` to resolve view by name.
Here is a guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that as well. I got to a point when I was able to fetch the file, but it doesn't compile the Mustache syntax. So, the page shows {{name}} instead of "Frank".

Comment: I just found a sample repo:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-mustache

I found the quickest way to resolve the problem is to change the suffix to .mustache instead of .html. For .html, I tried to override it in viewResolver and application;.properties for suffix/prefix properties. it doesn't recognized as mustache template. Therefore, it returned the entire text without compiling it.

Comment: It will be nice to have a working example to see how I can write viewResolver for mustache that works for recognizing other file extensions such as .html and custom template location.

Comment: It seems you didn't add {{name}} param to `ModelAndView`. 
`modelAndView.addObject("name", "Frank")`

Comment: So, it seems, you don't need to change file from *html* to *mustache*.

Comment: I did have the name param added to the model initially when I followed some online example, but I saw the 404 error. So, I just remove things where possible to  debug the issue. Finally, I rename the file extension, it works as is.

Comment: My template didn't use {{name}} or other mustache tag. It just has a word :"hello".

Answer (score 0):

For me, I finally found out that I should rename the file extension to .mustache instead of using .html. This will work with the out of the box configuration. Here is an example code I found online:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-mustache

I have not found out the exact way to override the template path and file extension while having the app still recognize it is a mustache template. So, it will compile before returning it.